# Run OS Commands with MQ Service object - AMQ8734- Command failed - Program could not be started

Tags: ibm-mq

I want to run a test command on MQ Server Windows Machine remotely. In order to do that, I use [SupportPac MO72](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg24007769&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&lang=en) and I can successfully connect remotely to MQ Server with Administrator ID. Now I have MQSC console available and I want to run some OS command with creating `SERVICE` object. I defined my service as:

> DEFINE SERVICE('myService') STARTCMD('C:\Windows\System32\PING.EXE 127.0.0.1') SERVTYPE(SERVER) CONTROL(MANUAL)

The service was created successfully and now I want to start this service, so I typed:

> START SERVICE(myService)

But I got this error:

> AMQ8734- Command failed - Program could not be started

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a combination of things wrong...

1. Your `SERVTYPE(SERVER)` is for something which starts running and stays running (and hence whose health is monitored). `SERVTYPE(COMMAND)` is for something you run and ends. Only a `SERVTYPE(SERVER)` can be monitored for health but it ought to be long running.
2. Your `startcmd` needs to be a binary to launch - just the binary. The `STARTARGS` need to hold the arguments to the command.

   ```
    DEFINE SERVICE('myService') +  
           STARTCMD('C:\Windows\System32\PING.EXE') +  
           STARTARG('127.0.0.1') +  
           SERVTYPE(COMMAND) +  
           CONTROL(MANUAL)
   ```

Of course, you might like to see its output - look at the args like `STDOUT` and `STDERR` to capture output into a file.

If you want the output to come back to your remote client in a queue it gets a bit more complicated. You would have to capture the output and pipe it through `amqsput` or some other program to get it onto a queue, then retrieve it.  The queue cannot be the same reply queue you are using with MO72 because MO72 would choke on the text, so you would have to use `amqsgetc` or some other program to fetch the output from the queue.